# Converting a KHS FLITE 223 into a freewheel fixie?

Tags: road-bike, freewheel, fixed-gear, conversion

I have this KHS Road bike that I got back in high school and was wondering if I'm able to convert it into a freewheel fixie (I think that's the right term) The bike does have vertical dropouts. Would it be cheaper to convert it or just buy a new bike altogether? 
Here is a link with all the specs I haven't changed anything since I got it!
https://khsbicycles.com/bikes/flite-223-16/[image]

Comment: Did you mean "single speed" ?  That lets you coast without pedalling, but does not offer any other gears.  A fixed speed means the cranks rotate all the time along with the wheel.

Comment: Related, but not dupe  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25142/trying-to-build-first-fixie

Comment: The correct term is fixed gear. It's the exact opposite of freewheel.

Comment: I enjoy riding a single speed bike very much. However, for this bike it is much better to use it as it is. If the gears aren't working, just fix them. As Criggie wrote, a conversion will involve a lot of work and will be costly. The result would be disappointing sinlge speed, unless you spend as much as a new, purpose built, single speed costs.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the photo from your link, this bike will be difficult to convert because of the dropout having no adjustment at all.

Effectively this means you will need some other way of tensioning the chain.

1. Eccentric bottom bracket (expensive)
2. Chain tensioner (looks like a derailleur) This also means you cannot use fixed gear, because the chain will go slack on the top run if you forget and try to coast.  Also means skid-braking is impossible.
3. Half-link chain (expensive, heavier, somewhat uglier)

Also in your shopping list will be a single-speed conversion kit, which is a single cog and a bunch of spacers to replace your rear cassette.

[image: https://www.wiggle.co.nz/dmr-simple-tension-seeker-single-speed-kit/]

Its probably advisable to fit a new chain at the time of conversion, to help keep track of mileage on components.

You might choose to replace your chainrings too, but that's more for aesthetics.  Its reasonable to pick a chainring, run the bike on only that ring by locking off the front derailleur.  You might choose to remove the inner grannie chainring for weight/appearances.  Removing the middle or large chainring will probably require a different set of chainring bolts, or some washers added to make up the missing thickness.

Brakes - For other future readers, just leave them on.   I am of the opinion that two brakes are mandatory on any road bike.  And that skid braking is not an effective emergency brake.  So don't strip off your rim brakes in the pursuit of appearance.  
 This doesn't apply to OP because the cassette conversion kit does not remove the freehub and the bike will just coast, if you try to skid stop on a single speed.

**UPSHOT**  compare the sum of cost of parts, with the loss of versatility of your quite-nice road bike.  Compare that with the cost of a second bike, and make a decision yourself as to which is more suitable.

I'd recommend N+1 if you can afford it, and would only consider conversion for a bike that isn't being used.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Criggie's answer...

Also consider removing the two chainrings you are not using (you may need shorter chainring bolts as one set go through the middle and outer rings.)

The usual configuration would be retaining the middle ring and removing the inner small and outer large rings, however as you will be using a single speed conversion kit you can position the single rear sprocket where you like on the freehub. This means you could use the outer chainring and adjust the chanline appropriately,

Comment: That positioning is necessary to get the chain line straight. Unless there is a tensioner, narrow-wide rings, or you keep the front mech the chain will be more likely to drop.

Answer (score 0):

Your gnna need a bmx chain because the the spaces on the geared chain are tooo small to fit on the freewheel/fixie cog and a few links frm a half link chain to reduce the slack on the chain since u cant adjust the distance frm the crank and the back tire. Its actually really simple to do. [image][image]

Comment: It also requires a new rear wheel. This bike doesn't have a tensioner and no adjustable dropouts. It either has an eccentric bottom bracket (about 100 €$£) or magic gear ratio (gears where chain just fits).